# Heroku Port Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, port, nodemailer

I am trying to use nodemailer with a deployed Heroku app which has all of the config variables loaded in heroku.  I used this basic example and was able to get it deployed and sending emails locally:

https://github.com/binhc/react-nodemailer

by changing this code:

```
    var transport = {
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  auth: {
    user: creds.USER,
    pass: creds.PASS
  }
}
```

to:

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    type: 'OAuth2',
    user: creds.user,
    clientId: creds.googleClientId,
    clientSecret: creds.googleClientSecret,
    refreshToken: creds.googleRefreshToken
  }
});
```

This is the error that I am getting when it doesn't send in heroku:

```
xhr.js:178 OPTIONS http://localhost:3002/send 0 ()
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:178
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:12
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:59
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js:51
wrap @ bind.js:9
Book._this.handleSubmit @ book.js:45
apply @ _apply.js:15
baseInvoke @ _baseInvoke.js:21
apply @ _apply.js:16
(anonymous) @ _overRest.js:32
(anonymous) @ Form.js:60
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:100
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:138
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:187
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:201
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:466
executeDispatchesInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:488
executeDispatchesAndRelease @ react-dom.development.js:586
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:597
forEachAccumulated @ react-dom.development.js:567
runEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:728
runExtractedEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:737
handleTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:4201
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:12537
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:1939
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4282
interactiveUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:12592
interactiveUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:1958
dispatchInteractiveEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4259
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)
```

Which I don't understand because I have this line of code:

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3002');
```

Shouldn't the port be automatically updating to whatever heroku sets it as?

Comment: Did you define `Procfile` before deploying it to Heroku? And how do you start your local server?

Comment: I didn't define a Procfile and am just using package.json scripts to start my local server.  Particularly I am using- `"dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""`, where my client starts react scripts and my server starts the node script

Comment: If you don't define procfile, heroku by default starts server by running `npm start`.
Where is your package.json file located? Is it outside of server and client folder?

Comment: I think I see the error `If no Procfile is present in the root directory of your app during the build process, your web process will be started by running npm start, a script you can specify in package.json` so it must be running just npm start which just starts the react script.  I will learn to create a procfile to run both

Comment: @Vikas I have a main folder with the server folder inside of it.  The server folder has a package.json and then the clients folder (which has the server solder inside of it) has one as well.  I need to eventually refractor for front and back end but that's how it's currently set up.  So I would assume that it's running npm start from the outermost package.json which is `"start": "react-scripts start"`

Comment: Right. But then it won't be able to start the server as its not able to run the command present in your server package.json. Also one heroku app can only run one application not both.

Comment: @Vikas how would one use nodemailer with a react app than if I can't have both running?

Comment: You need to run them on separate heroku apps and in your react heroku app you need to specify the base url of your backend server (which would be running on separate heroku app). I am away from my system otherwise i would have told you how to set the base url of backend application. I am pretty much sure you need to save that as an environment variable.